# What is the best way to run programs in parallel in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run command lines (programs) in parallel. so
I'm using **Thread**, **Process** and **ProcessBuilder** classes for that.
My laptop has 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

Test results of running *my.exe* programs in separate threads:

- 1 process   1 thread   16 min
- 2 processes 2 threads  20 min
- 2 processes 2 threads  51 min
- 4 processes 4 threads  34 min
- 8 processes 4 threads  83 min
- 8 processes 8 threads  68 min

So I see obvious trend => doesn't matter how many processes I split into separate threads, I would get only (approx) 50% speed increase. So I'm thinking that java splits all threads between 2 cores. Am I right? how to achieve better performance?

```
//general idea to wrap process into thread
class myThread extends Thread{
  String cmd;
  myThread(String cmd){
    this.cmd=cmd;
  }
  public void run(){
    try {
           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
           //run command line
           Process proc = pb.start();
           //wait until process finished
           proc.waitFor();    
         } catch(Exception e){
           //something wrong
        }
  }
}

public class myClass {
  public static void main(String args[]){
   //let say I have String array of command lines
   // and let's imagine I'm reducing array when do tests 
   // -param doesn't mean anything, so each command is the same in array
    String commandLines[] = {
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 1"
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 2",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 3"
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 4"
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 5",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 6",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 7",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 8",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 9",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 10",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 11",
     "C:\\myfolder\\my.exe\" -param 12"};

        myThread myThreadsArr[] = new myThread[commandLines.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<commandLines.length;i++){
           myThreadsArr[i]=new myThread(commandLines[i]);
           //this start thread which obviously call run()
           myThreadsArr[i].start();
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't explain what `my.exe` does and what are its parameters for, we can't help you.

Comment: I doubt that threads help here at all. Just create all of the processes in one thread, then wait for them all to complete. The "multiprocessing" would be handled by your OS.

Comment: Your code shows how you test "12 processes 12 threads" but how do you handle "8 processes 4 threads" do you wait until the first four threads are finished and start the second round or does every `myTask` get two `commandLines`?

Comment: I didn't post the code. I post the core of the code. my.exe is hypothetical program. In reality I run thirty part tool which is doing some calculations. So I split this calculations in parts expecting X time performance improvement. So the question more about best practice of running programs concurently.

Answer (score 0):

The number of thread depends upon process you are running.For an example if you are processing only CPU intensive work and you have 2 core ,so what ever thread you will create at the time 2 thread will run.Depending your system create a thread pool and submit your process as task.

The optimal number of threads to use depends on several factors, but mostly the number of available processors and how cpu-intensive your tasks are. 
optimal number of threads:

```
N_threads = N_cpu * U_cpu * (1 + W / C)
Where:

N_threads is the optimal number of threads
N_cpu is the number of prcessors, which you can obtain from Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
U_cpu is the target CPU utilization (1 if you want to use the full available resources)
W / C is the ratio of wait time to compute time (0 for CPU-bound task, maybe 10 or 100 for slow I/O tasks)
```

Comment: Does it mean i need split all processes into two threads? Or even one thread would run on two cores? My processes are highly depends on cpu speed, so they consume cpu highly.